# Sonar violation for dependency scope system

Tags: java, maven, sonarqube

Need help in resolving a sonar issue. We are using some third party jars which are not there on maven public repository.
I defined its dependency as:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>api</groupId>
            <artifactId>api</artifactId>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <systemPath>${project.basedir}\lib\api-1.0.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
```

But Sonar is giving a critical violation for it with message

> Update this scope and remove the "systemPath".

What is the right way of adding third party jar with maven which are not there on maven public repository.

Comment: I'm not sure how to solve this particular issue, but when sonarqube raises an issue it offers detailed information on why it's bad and how to fix it. there should be an option in the UI to access extra info.

Comment: I did look at the information provided by the sonarqube, but it only explains the issue and why it should not be used. It doesn't provide alternative ways that can be used to resolve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install in your local repo by running below maven command 
`mvn install:install-file -Dfile=api-1.0.jar`. This allows maven to have that jar without being fetched from remote repos.

Then, you don't need to specify the scope as `system`.

Comment: I installed the jar in my local repo and problem solved.

Answer (score 2):

You should install these dependencies in local maven repository as `maven clean install`

Or better to use [nexus repository manager](http://www.sonatype.org/nexus/category/nexus-oss/) or [artifactory](https://www.jfrog.com/artifactory/) and deploy there your dependencies.

Then you can use you library as a regular maven dependency

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>api</groupId>
        <artifactId>api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: I am not aware about the nexus repository manager and artifactory. There are just two external jars. Is it a good idea to deploy them. Are these repository free?

Comment: nexus is free and it will allow you to have local cache of all your dependencies in case of internet access failures. Using repository manager  is the regular practice for companies projects.

Comment: This is worst than providing the jar because it may not or should not be accessible from outside for security or license reasons.