SonarQube: Dependencies should not have "system" scope. Update this scope and remove the "systemPath"
I have a problem with this dependency in my pom.xml:
<dependency>
    <groupId>DB</groupId>
    <artifactId>DB</artifactId>
    <version>1</version>
    <scope>system</scope>
    <systemPath>${basedir}/src/main/resources/lib/Db.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>

How can I avoid this Sonar issue?
I can't use an internal repository, and we don't have a corporate one.
Thanks!
I need to get past that sonar check.

Can you use a local repository? If so, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44760764/sonar-violation-for-dependency-scope-system

I would like to propose you two solutions to get rid of the aforementioned Sonar issue. First one is a straightforward 'fix' to your issue, but please consider the second option as well.
Proposed Solution
Considering your case:

you can't use an (internal/corporate) repository
the referenced JAR file is not present in any public repository

My proposed solution would be to install the JAR file into your local Maven repository (located in ~/.m2/repository by default):
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=src/main/resources/lib/Db.jar -DgroupId=DB -DartifactId=DB -Dversion=1.0 -Dpackaging=jar

After that you can refer to this library in your pom.xml:
<dependency>
    <groupId>DB</groupId>
    <artifactId>DB</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>

Please consider providing a more meaningful groupId and artifactId, to avoid confusion later.
Refactoring Your Project
If you maintain the source code of the Db.jar file, I would like to recommend you move its source code into a separate module. To make it happen, refactor your Maven project into a multi-module project:

Define a parent Maven module
Add two submodules

A module called db for example which contains the code for the Db.jar library
A module which contains your current code, like main.


Add db module as a dependency of main module with compile scope.

I think it's a cleaner approach and you don't need to manually copy over Db.jar whenever you need to make changes in it.
